# Server error when trying to import to the database from an Excel file. Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel

When I try to select a value when loading data from excel, I get the error

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist, or access is denied. (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server)

I use Windows authentication login and can also create databases freely.

Import destination selection: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server. Server name: localhost – the same as when logging in
I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 19

Message: `[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist, or access is denied. (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server)`

[Program location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6vWj.png)

Comment: Please provide more detail on your problem. Include relevant code that produces the error.